# Can't change resolv.conf (tried other answers)

Tags: networking, dns, dhcp, resolv.conf

Seems that I can't change `resolv.conf`: changes are reset after reboot or disabling/enabling Wi-Fi. It contains `nameserver 127.0.0.1`, and I can't connect to any site. When I manually change it to `nameserver 8.8.8.8`, everything works.

What I've tried:

1. Changing `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base`. Currently it contains

   ```
   nameserver 8.8.8.8 
   nameserver 8.8.4.4
   ```
2. Editing `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf`

   It had the lines

   ```
   request subnet-mask, broadcast-address, time-offset, routers,
           dhcp6.domain-search, dhcp6.fqdn, dhcp6.sntp-servers, netbios-scope,
           interface-mtu,rfc3442-classless-static-routes, ntp-servers, 
           domain-name-servers, dhcp6.name-servers, netbios-name-servers;
   ```

   I removed the last three, added line

   ```
   prepend domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4;
   ```

   and ran `/etc/init.d/networking restart`, but it didn't help either.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, but, as I've said, I tried to change resolf.conf.d/head, tail and base. `sudo resolvconf -u` takes no effect on content of resolv.conf and only produces a warning: "/etc/resolvconf/update.d/libc: Warning: /etc/resolv.conf is not a symbolic link to /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf".
In Wi-Fi settings for network I'm using I've set 'Automatic (DHCP)' and entered `8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4` as DNS.

Comment: Solution with `echo 8.8.8.4 >> /etc/resolv.conf` on startup seems to work, but only until I reconnect to network.

Answer (score 2):

Install **resolvconf**: `sudo apt-get install resolvconf` and once done edit `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base` and put your nameservers in it:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8 
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

Once done, run `sudo resolvconf -u`

That should do it, alternatively, you can use a "workaround" (I would **not** unless I have to) and edit `/etc/rc.local` and put the following two lines:

```
echo 8.8.8.4 >> /etc/resolv.conf
echo 8.8.8.4 >> /etc/resolv.conf
```

That would append the lines to `/run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf` because `/etc/resolv.conf` is a symbolic link to `/run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf`.

But for that to run, the `/etc/rc.local` file must exist with the right content + permissions:

`-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 658 Feb 11 17:31 /etc/rc.local`

In case yours does not exist (and I wouldn't expect it to), create one with the following content and make sure you change the permissions as shown above:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

echo 8.8.8.4 >> /etc/resolv.conf
echo 8.8.8.4 >> /etc/resolv.conf

exit 0
```

I hope this helps.

Just for the record:

```
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=1637540k,mode=755
```

`/run` is a `tmpfs` which means any changes done to any path within`/run` are wiped out once you reboot your system.